# Add key-value-pair to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional array where I am trying to loop over my outer array, `$jsonarray`, and add a `'color'` key-value-pair to the inner arrays, based on the output of the switch. When I display the output in JSON the `'color'` fields are all set to null. The `$jsonarray` has a structure like this:

```
$jsonarray= [
    0=> [
        'deadline'     => 'deadline',
        'duedate'  => 'duedate',],
    1=> [
        'deadline'     => 'deadline',
        'duedate'  => 'duedate',],
```

And my code looks like so:

```
    $i = 0;
    $keys = array_keys($jsonarray);
    for ($k = 0; $k < count($jsonarray); $k++){
   foreach ($jsonarray[$keys[$k]] as $key => $value) {
     $color = 0;
     switch ($i) {
       case 0:
         $color = '#AED5F1';
         break;
       case 1:
         $color = '#F7D590';
         break;
       case 2:
         $color = '#EE8970';
         break;
     }
    array_push($jsonarray[$k]['color'], $color);
     $i++;
      }
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Provide source data `$jsonarray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```php
foreach ($jsonarray as $i => &$value) {
    switch ($i) {
        case 0:
            $value['color'] = '#AED5F1';
            break;
        case 1:
            $value['color'] = '#F7D590';
            break;
        case 2:
            $value['color'] = '#EE8970';
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for the first three `deadlines`! I may have forgot to describe my second issue which is that I want the three next `deadlines` to continue in the same pattern so that eg. `deadline` 4 corresponds with `case 0`. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: @sveggen use the modulo operator. change the switch statement to ```switch ($i % 3)```